# R: bar ggplot2 error: Faceting variables must have at least one value

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, plotly

I have an error when I try to plot my graph. This is the error message.

'Expected 2 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 1 rows [24216].Error: Faceting variables must have at least one value'

```
#Load Libaries

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
options(scipen = 100000)
library(scales)
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)

#Read dataset
ura <- read.csv('URAdata_new.csv') 

#Data cleaning
ura <- ura %>% mutate(Date.of.Sale_month = str_split(ura$Date.of.Sale, '-', simplify = T)[, 1],
               Date.of.Sale_year = str_split(ura$Date.of.Sale, '-', simplify = T)[, 2])

#Plotly Graph in issue
  
    Plot2 <- ggplotly(ura %>%
           separate(Date.of.Sale, c('Sale_year', 'Sale_month'), sep = '-') %>%
           filter(Sale_year %in% c(16, 17) & Postal.District %in% c(2, 5)) %>%
           group_by(Sale_year, Postal.District) %>%
           summarize(avg_price = mean(Price....)) %>%
           ggplot(aes(x = as.character(Postal.District), y = avg_price, 
                      fill = as.factor(Sale_year))) + 
           geom_col() + 
           facet_grid(~ as.factor(Sale_year)) +
           labs(x = 'Postal District', y = 'Average price', 
                title = 'Comparison of unit prices in district 2 and 5 between 2016 and 2017') +
           scale_fill_discrete(name = "Year of sale", labels = c("2016", "2017"))+
           theme(
             plot.title = element_text(colour="red",size=10, face="bold.italic",hjust = 0.5),
             axis.title.x = element_text(colour="blue",size=14, face="bold"),
             axis.title.y = element_text(colour="green",size=14, face="bold"), 
             legend.title=element_text(size=8))+
           scale_y_continuous(name="Average Price",labels = comma), main="foo")
Plot2
```

These are my codes above.

dput(head(ura,20)

```
structure(list(Project.Name = c("V ON SHENTON", "V ON SHENTON", 
"STIRLING RESIDENCES", "PARC CLEMATIS", "STIRLING RESIDENCES", 
"ONE PEARL BANK", "TWIN VEW", "WHISTLER GRAND", "WHISTLER GRAND", 
"WHISTLER GRAND", "WHISTLER GRAND", "WHISTLER GRAND", "KENT RIDGE HILL RESIDENCES", 
"KENT RIDGE HILL RESIDENCES", "KENT RIDGE HILL RESIDENCES", "KENT RIDGE HILL RESIDENCES", 
"KENT RIDGE HILL RESIDENCES", "KENT RIDGE HILL RESIDENCES", "KENT RIDGE HILL RESIDENCES", 
"STIRLING RESIDENCES"), Street.Name = c("SHENTON WAY", "SHENTON WAY", 
"STIRLING ROAD", "JALAN LEMPENG", "STIRLING ROAD", "PEARL BANK", 
"WEST COAST VALE", "WEST COAST VALE", "WEST COAST VALE", "WEST COAST VALE", 
"WEST COAST VALE", "WEST COAST VALE", "SOUTH BUONA VISTA ROAD", 
"SOUTH BUONA VISTA ROAD", "SOUTH BUONA VISTA ROAD", "SOUTH BUONA VISTA ROAD", 
"SOUTH BUONA VISTA ROAD", "SOUTH BUONA VISTA ROAD", "SOUTH BUONA VISTA ROAD", 
"STIRLING ROAD"), Type = c("Apartment", "Apartment", "Apartment", 
"Apartment", "Apartment", "Apartment", "Apartment", "Apartment", 
"Apartment", "Apartment", "Apartment", "Apartment", "Apartment", 
"Apartment", "Apartment", "Apartment", "Apartment", "Apartment", 
"Apartment", "Apartment"), Postal.District = c(1L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 
3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L
), Market.Segment = c("CCR", "CCR", "RCR", "OCR", "RCR", "RCR", 
"OCR", "OCR", "OCR", "OCR", "OCR", "OCR", "RCR", "RCR", "RCR", 
"RCR", "RCR", "RCR", "RCR", "RCR"), Tenure = c("99 yrs lease commencing from 2011", 
"99 yrs lease commencing from 2011", "99 yrs lease commencing from 2017", 
"99 yrs lease commencing from 2019", "99 yrs lease commencing from 2017", 
"99 yrs lease commencing from 2019", "99 yrs lease commencing from 2017", 
"99 yrs lease commencing from 2018", "99 yrs lease commencing from 2018", 
"99 yrs lease commencing from 2018", "99 yrs lease commencing from 2018", 
"99 yrs lease commencing from 2018", "99 yrs lease commencing from 2018", 
"99 yrs lease commencing from 2018", "99 yrs lease commencing from 2018", 
"99 yrs lease commencing from 2018", "99 yrs lease commencing from 2018", 
"99 yrs lease commencing from 2018", "99 yrs lease commencing from 2018", 
"99 yrs lease commencing from 2017"), Type.of.Sale = c("Resale", 
"Resale", "New Sale", "New Sale", "New Sale", "New Sale", "New Sale", 
"New Sale", "New Sale", "New Sale", "New Sale", "New Sale", "New Sale", 
"New Sale", "New Sale", "New Sale", "New Sale", "New Sale", "New Sale", 
"New Sale"), No..of.Units = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Price.... = c(3548000L, 
3490000L, 1987000L, 1745000L, 1227000L, 1702000L, 1899000L, 704380L, 
1129960L, 1145540L, 1473540L, 1421880L, 1367000L, 1360000L, 3000000L, 
870000L, 1711000L, 899000L, 870000L, 1249000L), Nett.Price.... = c("-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"), Area..Sqft. = c(1518L, 1518L, 
1055L, 1044L, 635L, 700L, 1249L, 441L, 764L, 764L, 990L, 958L, 
775L, 786L, 1776L, 484L, 958L, 484L, 484L, 635L), Type.of.Area = c("Strata", 
"Strata", "Strata", "Strata", "Strata", "Strata", "Strata", "Strata", 
"Strata", "Strata", "Strata", "Strata", "Strata", "Strata", "Strata", 
"Strata", "Strata", "Strata", "Strata", "Strata"), Floor.Level = c("46 to 50", 
"46 to 50", "26 to 30", "06 to 10", "31 to 35", "21 to 25", "26 to 30", 
"21 to 25", "21 to 25", "21 to 25", "31 to 35", "31 to 35", "01 to 05", 
"01 to 05", "01 to 05", "01 to 05", "01 to 05", "01 to 05", "01 to 05", 
"16 to 20"), Unit.Price...psf. = c(2338L, 2299L, 1884L, 1671L, 
1932L, 2433L, 1521L, 1596L, 1479L, 1499L, 1488L, 1484L, 1764L, 
1731L, 1689L, 1796L, 1786L, 1856L, 1796L, 1967L), Date.of.Sale = c("20-Jun", 
"20-Jun", "20-Jun", "20-Jun", "20-Jun", "20-Jun", "20-Jun", "20-Jun", 
"20-Jun", "20-Jun", "20-Jun", "20-Jun", "20-Jun", "20-Jun", "20-Jun", 
"20-Jun", "20-Jun", "20-Jun", "20-Jun", "20-Jun")), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Google Sheet link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QFXNUpgEjjPGdfXUwvzYIadnoxcD2-Ba6cw6BqrxfO8/edit

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to run `str_split` code as well as `separate` code together, run only 1 of them.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

ura <- read.csv('URA Dataset  - URAdata_new.csv')

ggplotly(ura %>%
     separate(Date.of.Sale, c('Sale_year', 'Sale_month'), sep = '-') %>%
     filter(Sale_year %in% c(16, 17) & Postal.District %in% c(2, 5)) %>%
     group_by(Sale_year, Postal.District) %>%
     summarize(avg_price = mean(Price....)) %>%
     ggplot(aes(x = as.character(Postal.District), y = avg_price, 
                fill = as.factor(Sale_year))) + 
     geom_col() + 
     facet_grid(~ as.factor(Sale_year)) +
     labs(x = 'Postal District', y = 'Average price', 
          title = 'Comparison of unit prices in district 2 and 5 between 2016 and 2017') +
     scale_fill_discrete(name = "Year of sale", labels = c("2016", "2017"))+
     theme(
       plot.title = element_text(colour="red",size=10, face="bold.italic",hjust = 0.5),
       axis.title.x = element_text(colour="blue",size=14, face="bold"),
       axis.title.y = element_text(colour="green",size=14, face="bold"), 
       legend.title=element_text(size=8))+
     scale_y_continuous(name="Average Price",labels = comma), main = 'foo')
```

[image]